# Variables that store DB queries in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little Rails beginners question:

inside my Rails helper, I created method that I'm using to show a price in my view:

```
    def price    
     pricea = Hotel.order(wdpricenm: :asc).first 
     priceb = Hotel.order(wepricenm: :asc).first

     if (pricea.wdpricenm + priceb.wepricenm) < (priceb.wdpricenm + priceb.wepricenm) 
       return (pricea.wdpricenm + priceb.wepricenm)
     else 
       return (priceb.wdpricenm + priceb.wepricenm) 
     end

   <td><%= price %></td>
```

Its works without problems but I'd like to put the pricea / priceb variables (that store the queries) somewhere else in the rails application since I want to use them for other methods as well.

My Question is therefore: What would you suggest where to put those price variables in Rails and especially what variable types would you use?

Thanks for all replies in advance,

Cheers Rob

Comment: No variables. *Refactor* the code. Break the logic for two price query into 2 more methods. Call them inside `price`, and call them any where you want to use them..That's good trick I can tell you..

Comment: its different queries > WDpricenm: :asc and the other WEpricenm: :asc - this is just a fragment of the real code that I want to refactor because I dont want to put those query variable in several methods ... looks ugly ... could you give me an example of your suggestion above?

Comment: Low vision power I have gained recently..... Lollz

Comment: Create one method `calc_pricea` and one `calc_priceb`.. Then shift the logic to them respectively into those.. so.. now call them inside your method `price` to get the job done. And if you need to use the result of either of the new re-factored methods anywhere else.. call them from that place.. Don't go for any powerful variable like Global..

Comment: Your code is not clear. Could you explain `w(e/d)pricenm`, what you are returning from the queries, why you are conditionally returning price based on `price(a/b)`. With that, we should be able to advise on a better structure... but I'd start with creating more descriptive variables.

Comment: thanks arup and damien, @damien the variable name is quite confusing but it means Weekend-price-normal and weekday-price-normal. I'm doing this since I have quite a view different prices in the DB and I'm ordering the table to find the smallest price.

Answer (score 4):

Use scope: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

```
Class Hotel < ActiveRecord:Base
  scope :pricea, -> { order(wdpricenm: :asc).first }
  scope :priceb, -> { order(wepricenm: :asc).first }
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot Jorge and Arkhitech, how can I get wdpricenm from :priceb where I ordered the table according to wepricenm asc in the method? is it something like Hotel.priceb(wdpricenm) ?

Comment: You would simply do Hotel.priceb.wdpricenm

Answer (score 1):

```
Class Hotel < ActiveRecord:Base

  def self.pricea
    self.order(wdpricenm: :asc).first
  end

  def self.priceb
    self.order(wepricenm: :asc).first
  end

end
```

Now you are able to use:

```
pricea = Hotel.pricea
priceb = Hotel.priceb
```

If you need those prices available in different views you can do in the controllers:

```
Before_action :retrieve_prices, only: [:action1, :action2]

def retrieve_prices
  @pricea = Hotel.pricea
  @priceb = Hotel.priceb
end
```

This way this variables will be available only for the selected actions, and the methods can be reused anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: per comment

In the model:

```
Class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :weekday_min, -> { where(minimum(:wdpricenm)).first }
  scope :weekend_min, -> { where(minimum(:wepricenm)).first }

  def self.best_deal(weekdays, weekend_days)
    weekday_min_tot = (weekdays * weekday_min.wdpricenm) + (weekend_days * weekday_min.wepricenm)
    weekend_min_tot = (weekend_days * weekend_min.wdpricenm) + (weekend_days * weekend_min.wepricenm)

    [weekday_min_tot, weekend_min_tot].min
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```
@best_deal = Hotel.best_deal
```

Display total price in the view(no hint as to which hotel though):

```
<%= @best_deal %>
```

Note the lack of helpers.

ALSO NOTE: The best deal might not be either of these choices. What you need is to calculate the total for each hotel and then take the minimum of that.

You have a bit of a journey ahead of you picking up Rails. It's a big bite. I recommend the Hartl tutorial to start with. And don't forget to learn Ruby.

Comment: thanks seph, what i'm trying to achieve is to find out: if 'sum of weekdays' * pricea.withweekdays (table ordered by the cheapest weekday price) +  'sum of weekenddays' * pricea.withweekENDdays is < or > as 'sum of weekdays' * priceb.withweekdays (table ordered by the cheapest weekENDday price) +  'sum of weekenddays' * priceb.withweekENDdays

Comment: @RobBerlin - I modified the code according to your comment. This still might not be what you are after. See notes above.